# Why are users from "rest of world" countries landing to our UK site and not our defined ROW site?

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation, geotargeting

I have my site set up so that users from uk will land on /uk and then everyone else lands to /rw (rest of world) however I am seeing a large portion of traffic from ROW countries landing on the UK site.

I have taken all directional links out of campaigns etc and the site should direct and serve based on IP address. The mapping I have in the backend is correct for directing and I have even implemented a fix with my internet security software so as not to mask the IP but this hasn't done anything

This is effecting traffic coming from all sources at a consistent rate and the overall amount of traffic hitting the wrong site is upwards of 80%

Below is a screenshot of top 5 traffic channels from ROW countries vs traffic from ROW countries that isn't landing to the /rw site over the last 7 days.

[image]

We have reviewed the hreflang tags multiple times but this hasn't made any impact and as seen in the screenshot, organic is still heavily affected.

What could possibly be stopping the serving from working?

Comment: Are you using geo IP redirection? Or just relying on the `hreflang` tags? For other users to diagnose the issue then you'll need to post the details of your geo targeting method.

Comment: I'm curious about your setup for this:
"I have my site set up so that users from uk will land on /uk and then everyone else lands to /rw".
Explaining this would be helpful